# How should i avoid global variable between 2 JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, global-variables

In my software i have a JFrame with 2 JPanels...

What i need is in jpanel1 to have a tool to choose a color, and in jpanel2 "draw" with this color...

Now, the problem is: how can i know from jpanel2 what color i have choosed in jpanel 1?

Or better, which is the best way to share variables between 2 jcomponents that only thing have in common is the parent?

---

I don't know if this question allready exists, i searched a bit about it but didn't find anything that can help me...

Comment: You could use an observer pattern to alert panel2 that some property in panel1 has changed. Alternatively, you could supply some of getter method(s) in panel1, which panel2 could call when it needs to know what it should be doing...

Comment: panel2 doesn't know about panel1, i could use a getter only from inside the frame class, not the panel2 class...

Comment: If you're using an observer pattern, you could link them all together via interfaces

Comment: *"What i need is in jpanel1.."*  That is the point at which your IDE has made you it's bitch.  If you simply used instances of panels instead of extending them, the code would not present this difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify your question, the issue is how to share an object's state (here the value held by a Color field), with another object. A simplistic but correct answer is to give the class that needs the new Color a reference to the class that holds the changing Color field, and also to give the changing Color field a getter method, i.e.,

```
public Color getSelectedColor() {
   return selectedColor;
}
```

The hard part is knowing *when* to request this information. For this consider

1. Displaying the the changing Color field JPanel in a modal JDialog (or JOptionPane). Then knowing when the change occurs and when to request the information is trivial.
2. If this is not feasable, consider having the the class with changing Color field *push* the information to the requesting class, after the change occurs... or
3. Consider having the requesting class *pull* the information out of the class with the changing Color field using some type of listener or observer set up. I've used a PropertyChangeListener successfully for this, and note that Swing components already have innate support for this.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> But jpanel2 doesn't know about jpanel1 so i can't simply call jpanel1.getSelectedColor() from inside jpanel2...

Options here include giving jpanel2 a jpanel1 field and passing into it a valid reference to the currently displayed jpanel1 object, and then yes jpanel2 can call this method. Alternatively, you could keep them ignorant of each other, and instead have a control class call

```
jpanel2.setSelectedColor(jpanel1.getSelectedColor());
```

in a PropertyChangeListener, or something to this effect.

Comment: But jpanel2 doesn't know about jpanel1 so i can't simply call jpanel1.getSelectedColor() from inside jpanel2...